# VBA class method to return object reference from array

Tags: vba, tree

I'm trying to build an object tree to reference an hierarchic organisation. I've created a Node class which has a costcenter attribute and an array of Node objects.

Starting from the root node, each one can have an array of child node which can themselves have arrays of child nodes.

I have this method that I want to return a reference of the child object located in the array of its parent. It needs to return it as a pointer not a copy of the object because I want to be able to navigate thru the entire tree from the leaves to the root. I get this error : Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Is anyone would know what I'm missing?

```
'Node Class Module
Option Explicit

Dim children() As Node
Private arraySize As Integer
Private costcenter As Long

Public Function addChild(child As Long)

On Error GoTo addChild_Error

If IsNull(arraySize) Then
arraySize = 0
End If

' increment the arraysize variable
arraySize = arraySize + 1

'redimension the array of one more space
ReDim Preserve children(arraySize + 1)

Dim i As Integer
i = arraySize - 1

Set children(i) = New Node

children(i).setCostCenter (child)

addChild_Exit:

Exit Function

addChild_Error:

Debug.Print Err.Source


End Function

Public Function getChildrenCount() As Integer

If Not IsNull(arraySize) Then
getChildrenCount = arraySize
Else
getChildrenCount = 0
End If

End Function

Public Function setCostCenter(cc As Long)

costcenter = cc

End Function

Public Function child(cc As Long) As Node

If arraySize > 0 Then

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To arraySize Step 1

        Debug.Print children(i).getCostcenter

        If children(i).getCostcenter = cc Then

        Debug.Print "found"

   'getting error on the next line
        Set child = children(i)

        End If    
    Next i
End If

End Function
```

testing in the following subroutine:

```
Public Sub testCCnodes()

Dim root As Node
Set root = New Node
'initiate root
root.setCostCenter (103100) 
'add first level
root.addChild (206680)
root.addChild (206010)
root.addChild (205480)
root.addChild (205290)

'testing addChild
Dim limit As Integer
limit = root.getChildrenCount() - 1

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To limit Step 1

Debug.Print root.getChild(i)

Next i

'add a second level
Dim str As String
With root.child(205290)    'getting error on this line

   .addChild (205460)
   .addChild (205450)
   .addChild (205400)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: looks like your child functions isn't returning anyting, use the locals window and look at root, before the error line.  Can you post all the node class code.  what is child, also, should set child=new node come before?

Comment: Concur with the other comments.  I suspect the issue is with the one of the other functions.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I've edited my post to include the rest of the code. `getChild()` returns the CostCenter of child object in the array at index I. It does return values so that's tells me the object must had been initiated...

Comment: The problem is in the function `addChild` where the first Redim alocates three items but only the first one is actually available. Then in the function `child` you go through the `children` but `Set child = children(i)` causes error for `i > 0`. Fix the function `addChild` and add `Exit Function` after `Set child = children(i)
        Exit Function`, becasue it is not necessary to continue searching when the item was already found. IMO it will by much easier to use `VBA-Collection` instaed of `VBA-array`.

Comment: I've added the `Exit Function` and it worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment using VBA-Collection should be much more easier. Example:

> Node Class Module

```
Option Explicit

Private m_children As VBA.Collection
Private m_costcenter As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_children = New VBA.Collection
End Sub

Public Function AddChild(ByRef newChild As Node)
    m_children.Add newChild, CStr(newChild.Costcenter)
End Function

Public Property Get ChildrenCount() As Integer
    ChildrenCount = m_children.Count
End Property

Public Property Get Costcenter() As Long
    Costcenter = m_costcenter
End Property

Public Property Let Costcenter(ByVal vNewValue As Long)
    m_costcenter = vNewValue
End Property

Public Function Child(cc As Long) As Node
    Dim ch As Node
    For Each ch In m_children
        If ch.Costcenter = cc Then
            Set Child = ch
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ch
    ' Note that this function can still return Nothing here
End Function
```

> Test

```
Public Sub testCCnodes()
    Dim root As Node
    Set root = New Node
    root.Costcenter = 103100

    Dim newChild As Node
    Set newChild = New Node
    newChild.Costcenter = 205290
    root.AddChild newChild

    Set newChild = New Node
    newChild.Costcenter = 205460

    With root.Child(205290)
        .AddChild newChild
        ' and so on
        ' ...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks dee. It is not a class I knew before but it seems a lot easier to use like you say. My code is working now but I will follow your suggestion in order to avoid future problems

Comment: The performance would improve tremendously if you either used the key you store to return items in `Child` (with an error handler for bad keys) or used a `Dictionary` (allows non-string keys and has and `Exists` function).

Comment: @Comintern you are absolutely right! I was trying to write code which looked similar to the code in question, but it is not suitable for performance. If there should be performance problems it should be refactored to use either `key` or `Scripting-Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

`arraySize` is an Integer.  The initial value of a Numeric types is 0.  Numeric types can never be null.

> If IsNull(arraySize) Then arraySize = 0 End If

Increment count

> arraySize = arraySize + 1

Redim array to be larger than connter?

ReDim Preserve children(arraySize + 1)

**Set the reference to the 3rd to last element in the array**

> i = arraySize - 1
>
> Set children(i) = New Node

The problem is that you counter is off.

### Here is a much simpler pattern

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    arraySize = -1
End Sub

Public Function addChild(child As Long)
    arraySize = arraySize + 1
    ReDim Preserve children(arraySize)

    Set children(arraySize) = New Node
    children(arraySize).setCostCenter (child)

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. I've edited my post to include the addChild() function of the Node Class. You can see that the object is initiated into the array this way: `Set children(i) = New Node`

`children(i).setCostCenter (child)`

Comment: @SamuelLaroche  I updated my answer.  The problem seems to be with our `arraySize` counter.  I personally would use a some type of collection.  Dee's answer has an excellent example.